# date_format() not working in symfony 2.3 version controller

Tags: php, symfony

I had upgraded my project symfony2.0 version to symfony2.3 .Now the date_format() is not working but its working well in symfony2.0 .Please help me to work out this problem .

Comment: Please provide some code and if possible a stack trace. We can't read minds.

Comment: $date="2013/08/21";echo date_format($date,'Y-m-d'); this will work in symfony2.0 but not in symfony2.3

Comment: That's not a symfony question, see the documentation of [date_format](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.format.php), it needs a DateTime Object, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

$date = new DateTime('2013-08-10');
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d'));

It works for me.